# Ansible common variables for multiple inventories

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I would like to define a set of variables that must be inherited by any inventory I will use with playbooks. At the moment I have the following folder structure:

```
inventory/
  inv1.yml
  inv2.yml
playbooks/
  group_vars/
    all.yml
    inv1.yml
    inv2.yml
  play1.yml
  play2.yml
```

This structure allows me to inherit from `all.yml` the common variables, but if I need to override some of them I need to create a custom `group_vars` file: I read the [variable precedence rules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence) and understood that this is the expected behavior.

I would like to know if I can change something in my file organization to override common variables with definitions in inventory files. This would allow me to avoid splitting common overrides in a separate file and specific variables in inventory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found myself a solution (probably better say hack) that fits my requirements based on [multi inventory support](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_inventory.html#using-multiple-inventory-sources): I replaced `playbooks/group_vars/all.yml` with a fake inventory called `inventory/all.yml` that only contains host group `all` and defines default values for variables (no hosts are in this inventory).

Then I run the playbook with command:

```
$ ansible-playbook playbooks/play1.yml -i inventory/all.yml -i inventory/inv1.yml
```

This way I can override variables defined in `inventory/all.yml` with the ones in `inventory/inv1.yml`.

I am not 100% happy with this solution because it forces me to explicitly define in command line 2 inventories, so I sign this as the accepted answer but I wiil keep looking for improvements.

Answer (score 0):

Q: ***"Override common variables with definitions in inventory files."***

A: The variables from inventory files (precedence 3.) override only command line values (precedence 1.) and role defaults (precedence 2.). They can't override any higher precedence. In particular, any *group_vars/all* have got higher precedence.

The answer is no. It's not possible to override *group_vars/all* common variables with definitions in inventory files by changing the organization of the files.

---

For example, the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat inventory/inv1
[inv1]
host1
host2

[inv1:vars]
test_var=inventory/inv1
```

and the playbook

```yaml
shell> cat playbooks/play1.yml 
- hosts: all
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: test_var
```

gives

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook -i inventory/inv1 playbooks/play1.yml

PLAY [all] *****************************************************************

TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  test_var: inventory/inv1
ok: [host2] => 
  test_var: inventory/inv1
```

The variable will be overridden from any *group_vars/all*, e.g.

```yaml
shell> cat playbooks/group_vars/all
test_var: playbooks/group_vars/all
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [debug] ***************************************************************
ok: [host1] => 
  test_var: playbooks/group_vars/all
ok: [host2] => 
  test_var: playbooks/group_vars/all
```